# uwp how to delete a line

Tags: line, win-universal-app

```
public void CreateALine(double x1, double y1)
    {
        // Create a Line
        Line redLine = new Line();
        redLine.X1 = x + 20;
        redLine.Y1 = y + 20;
        redLine.X2 = x1 + 20;
        redLine.Y2 = y1 + 20;


        SolidColorBrush gBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
        gBrush.Color = Colors.Green;
        redLine.StrokeThickness = 2;
        redLine.Stroke = gBrush;

        // Add line to the Canvas
        canvas2.Children.Add(redLine);

    }
```

Here is my code, now I want to delete this line, can anyone tell me how to do this?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Children property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.panel.children.aspx) is nothing more than a [UIElementCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.uielementcollection.aspx) object attached to the [Canvas control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.canvas.aspx).

The `UIElementCollection` object has some methods that allow you to remove objects from itself, which may vary depending on the programming language.

[image]

In your case, the [Remove](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.uielementcollection.remove.aspx) and [RemoveAt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj635387.aspx) should solve your problem. All you need to do is to hold a reference of the item you want to remove and pass it as a parameter to the appropiate remove method **unless** you know its index in the collection; in which case you can remove it using that instead.